# I am new to flex containers trying to create a grid that will have all rows be the same height. Need some help figuring out what i am doing wrong

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I cant seem to get the text inside the elements to shrink though. I am using flex but can understand why the text in the element doesnt shrink, even thought i tell it to do so. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
<div  class="tw-flex tw-border">
      <div 
        v-for="(item, index) in cart" 
        class="tw-flex tw-flex-col tw-flex-shrink" 
        :class="{'tw-font-semibold': index==0}"
      >

        <component 
          :is="item.model.link ? 'a':'div'" 
          :href="item.model.link | ''"
          class="tw-border-b tw-w-full tw-flex-grow-0 tw-p-2 "
          :class="[index !== cart.length - 1 ? 'tw-border-r' : '']"
        >
          {{item.model.name}}
        </component>

        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.price}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.frame}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.loadCapacity}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.folding}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.wheels}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.straps}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.kickstand}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.padding}}</div>
        <div class=" tw-flex-grow-0 tw-border ">{{item.hardware}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: *I am using flex but can understand why the text in the element doesnt shrink* That's default flex behavior, flex sets a min width/height equal to content. if you want to override this set `min-width:0` or height `min-height:0`

Comment: Not sure what your `tailwind.config.js` looks like and also which version of tailwind you're using. The newest tailwind version is using the following classes `.flex-grow` and `.flex-grow-0`.